A map of $A$-modules is an isomorphism for any $M$,$N$ iff $r: A \rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism
I'm trying to understand the accepted answer in this question.
Context: Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ be a morphism of commutative rings. Let $M,N$ be $S$-modules. Then there is a natural morphism $\phi : M \otimes_R N \rightarrow M \otimes_S N$ of $R$-modules given by sending $m \otimes n \mapsto m \otimes n$. We want to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism for all $M$ and $N$ if and only if $f$ is an epimorphism.
I've narrowed my problems down to the following phrases in the accepted answer:
A) The equivalence "$S \otimes_R S \rightarrow S \otimes_S S \cong S$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f:R \rightarrow S$ is an epimorphism";
B) The condition '$m: S \otimes_R S \rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism' is "sufficient because if $f$ is an isomorphism then it induces a natural transformation which is also an isomorphism";
C) "Formally, there's a functor (even a monoidal functor) from the category of $(S,S)$-bimodules and bimodule homomorphisms to the category of functors $\text{Mod}(S) \times \text{Mod}(S) \rightarrow \text{Ab}$ and natural transformations, and it sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms".
My specific questions:

I'd like a proof of (A).

Context: The question seems to imply that we want to apply the fact about restriction of scalars being fully faithful when $f$ is an epimorphism (proof here), but I don't see how $S \otimes_R S$ is obtained by restricting scalars from some $S$-module.

I'd like an explanation of (B).

In particular, what functors is the natural transformation between, why is it an isomorphism, and why do we need $f$ to be an isomorphism?

I'd like an explanation of why (B) means that $m$ being an isomorphism is sufficient.

Context: I think it is clear that $m$ being an isomorphism is sufficient, because we just tensor with $\text{id}$ on both sides which gives us an isomorphism. Is this all that is being abstractified in this natural transformation or is something else going on here? Again, why do we require $f$ to be an isomorphism?

Can someone explain how (C) relates?

In particular, why does (C) refer to a functor but (B) refer to a natural transformation? I assume $S \otimes_R S$ is the relevant object in the category of $(S,S)$-bimodules; what is the relevant bit corresponding to the category of functors $\text{Mod}(S) \times \text{Mod}(S) \rightarrow \text{Ab}$? Is the fact that it sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms just rephrasing the statement?


I'd really appreciate some help in understanding this. I'm happy to clarify anything that isn't clear.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
